# Cloning a branch, keeping the history, removing attachments to other repos

Tags: git

I am working on a project there is a branch of a repo that I only need that branch. I have cloned that branch locally. I would like to keep the history but remove the attachment to the repo I cloned it from.

So basically make a new separate master repository from a branch but keep it's revision history.

Comment: So you have a branch `A` on a remote `X` and you want this branch to become the `master` branch on a remote `Y`?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want a clean repository on the end, i.e., only a `master` branch associated to the new remote.

```
# Reset master to your branch:
git reset --hard origin/A

# Update the remote and push:
git remote set-url origin NEW_REMOTE_URL

# Push:
git push -u origin master

# Prune the remote (remote references that are not on the new remote):
git remote prune origin
```

A bit more details:

- `git reset --hard origin/A` — This updates the local `master` reference to points to `origin/A`.
- `git remote set-url origin NEW_REMOTE_URL` — This  updates the remote URL for the `origin` upstream.
- `git push -u origin master` — This pushes your local `master` branch to the `origin` upstream.
- `git remote prune origin` — This remove all local references to branches on the `origin` upstream. Since the upstream only contains your `master` branch, this will remote all references.

Comment: Will this maintain the revision history to the files in the repo? If so thank you so much.

Comment: @Massman8039 This will keep the history of the `A` branch (all the commits leading to this branch and thus all the corresponding file changes).

Comment: Excellent. This is the exact solution I was hoping for.